# jQuery toggle function doesnt do anything

Tags: jquery

I want class .lrm to show up whenever I click class a with jquery I disabled .lrm with css `display:none;` and want to show up with jquery toggle method

```
<div id="main">
        <h1>Boora boora</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <a href="#">More info</a>
        <p class="lrm">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
    </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    })
    $(this).closest('#main').find('.lrm').toggle('fast');
})
```

Comment: Move the command that toggles INSIDE the click handler. It is OUTSIDE the click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the command that toggles INSIDE the click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('#main').find('.lrm').toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery toggle function doesnt do anything

Sure it does.  Yours just isn't being executed because there's no matching element(s).

This line isn't in your click handler:

```
$(this).closest('#main').find('.lrm').toggle('fast');
```

It executes once when the page loads (well, when the document is ready).  And at that time `this` is the `document`, which has no closest `#main`.  Since `.closest()` returns an empty set, `find` is never executed and `toggle` is never executed.

Put the line *inside* the click handler:

```
$('#main').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('#main').find('.lrm').toggle('fast');
});
```